# Emacs not finding gem binaries

Tags: ruby, emacs, rspec, rvm, zsh

I'm currently using [prelude](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude) without any noticeable modifications and [rvm](https://rvm.io). Some emacs packages like `rspec-mode` or `rcodetools` launch and pipe content through binaries provided by ruby gems.

My shell (zsh) has correct paths set up, so i can run `rspec` from my prompt, but emacs has not correctly set up the path it seems.

```
echo $PATH
/Users/flo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/Users/flo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@global/bin:/Users/flo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/Users/flo/bin/:/usr/games:/Users/flo/libs/go/bin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/Users/flo/.rvm/bin
```

For example, `M-x shell-command rspec` yields:
    zsh:1: command not found: rspec

What is necessary to make emacs recognise my `$PATH`?

Comment: `M-! echo $PATH RET` to print the path (`M-!` is bound to `shell-command` by default). Also, there must be a typo somewhere, because `M-x shell-command spec` shouldn't run `rspec` (unless you have an alias which you should tell us).

Comment: Yep, `spec` was a type, I edited my question.

The output of `M-! echo $PATH RET` is `/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/Users/flo/bin/:/u\
sr/games:/usr/local/share/npm/bin`

Comment: See? Wrong `$PATH`. The question now becomes: how do you start Emacs? Inside your shell, or using an application bundle?

Comment: I'm starting emacs from my shell. The path in my shell is correct though, as I mentioned in my question already. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Can you post the output of `print $PATH && emacs --batch --eval '(message (getenv "PATH"))' && emacs --batch --eval '(shell-command "print $PATH")'`? The output of first and second commands should be the same, and the third one should be somewhat different because `shell-command` is like `zsh -c`, where `.zshenv` is sourced.

Comment: The output of the first two commands is:

`/Users/flo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/Users/flo/.rvm/gems/ruby-     2.2.1@global/bin:/Users/flo/.rvm/rubies/ruby- 2.2.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/Users/flo/bi n/:/usr/games:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/Users/flo/.rvm/bin`

The third command `emacs --batch --eval '(shell-command "print $PATH")'` doesn't output anything.